# Adjective & Adverbial forms of "Conspiracy"

Tags: adjectives, synonyms, adverbs

I tried looking up its synonyms  (plot, scheme) and then their adjectives, but they didn't quite cut it. Any word that can be used as its adjective and adverb?

The place that I would like to use it is this:

> Keep your *conspiracy-theory-like* ideology to yourself, and don't spread what you can't prove.

Comment: Have you checked at [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conspiracy?s=t)? They have a list of related terms, including adjective and adverbs.

Answer (score 6):

You may need to give an example of where you want to use it, but *conspiratorial* and *conspiratorially* may fit.

Comment: Isn't *conspiratorially* an adverb ?

Comment: @speedyGonzales: The question text asks for an adverb. Perhaps I should have edited the title as well...

Comment: Then tags too because it should be in context.

Answer (score 1):

How about [conspiratory](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conspiratory) , [conspirative](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conspirative) and I think conspiracy is adjective itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Keep your ***[paranoid](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/paranoid)*** ***conspiracy-theorist*** ideology to yourself, and don't spread what you can't prove.